# StatusBarOrientation doesn't give correct answer

Tags: objective-c

I'm checking if the device is in landscape mode or in portrait when a button is pressed with this code:

```
orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]statusBarOrientation];

- (void)buttonclick
{
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    {
        NSLog(@"port");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Land");
    }
}
```

In this case it logs land, even thought the simulator is in portrait mode. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `orientation` *inside* your method:

```
- (void)buttonClick {
  orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

  if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
  {
    NSLog(@"port");
  }
  else
  {
    NSLog(@"Land");
  }
```

}